# Bring a subview of a UITableViewCell to the very front

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a `UITextField` within a container view in my `UITableViewCell`. I want to bring its container to the very front when the text field is tapped. To clarify: I added a subview to "mask" the background when the text field is tapped, so only the text field is showing. However I am having trouble with some methods i've tried:

1. `self.view.bringSubviewToFront(subview1)`
   This does not seem to work even if I have a reference to the view in my `UIViewController`, I am guessing it is because the view is buried too deep (but i'm not entirely sure)?
2. `self.view.insertSubview(subview1, aboveSubview: maskBackgroundView)` 
   This does bring the subview to the front, but it screws up the constraints I set on the subview.

Comment: hide your view until tap, then show it.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the `view.hidden` property to control the look, rather than shifting the order. `view.hidden = true` hides the view, while `false` displays it.